# Почему не могу работать с массивом?

Tags: java

```
public class Experement1 extends JApplet{
    int[] arr = new int[16];
    arr[0] = 1;

    int x1 = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите 1 елемент матрицы"));
    int x6 = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите 5 елемент матрицы"));
    int x11 = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите 11 елемент матрицы"));
    int x16 = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите 16 елемент матрицы"));
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for(int i=0;i<200;i+=100){
            for(int k=0;k<200;k+=100){
                g.drawOval(i, k, 10, 10);
            }
            if(x1==1){
                g.drawOval(9, 0, 20, 20);
                g.drawLine(9, 9, 10, 20);
                g.drawLine(9, 9, 20, 10);
            }
            if(x6==1){
                g.drawOval(109, 0, 20, 20);
                g.drawLine(109, 9, 110, 20);
                g.drawLine(109, 9, 120, 10);
            }
            if(x11==1){
                g.drawOval(9, 100, 20, 20);
                g.drawLine(9, 109, 10, 120);
                g.drawLine(9, 109, 20, 110);
            }
            if(x16==1){
                g.drawOval(109, 100, 20, 20);
                g.drawLine(109, 109, 110, 120);
                g.drawLine(109, 109, 120, 110);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Всеравно ошибка!!!Помогите плиз!!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: оформите ошибку в виде текста, а не скриншота

Answer (score 1):

Лучше бы вам конечно перенести логику инициализации массива `arr` в конструктор.

Но можно использовать нестатический блок инициализации:

```
public class Experement1 extends JApplet {
    int[] arr;
    {
        arr = new int[16];
        arr[0] = 1;    
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: всеравно ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Ой. Дело вовсе не в этом. Вы обращаетесь к элементу массива вне метода. Вот и беда.

```
int[] arr = new int[16];
arr[0] = 1;
```

Перенесите `arr[0] = 1;` в начало метода `public void paint(Graphics g)`.